# JSONObject resolve field with Enums

Tags: android, json, kotlin, enums

In my application i have several json responses from server and they all have a specific field calles "ac"

```
{ "ac": "register" / "upload" / "delete" etc
```

I want to have an Enum that will take tha json and return me the type

```
enum class MyResponses(val json: String) {

        REGISTER("register"),
        UPLOAD("upload"),
        DELETE("delete");

        companion object {
            fun toEvent(json: JSONObject): MyResponses {

                 var action = 
                 if (json.has("ac"))
                    json.getString("ac")
                else ""

                return when {
                    (REGISTER.action) -> REGISTER
                    (UPLOAD.action) -> UPLOAD
                    (DELETE.action) -> DELETE
                    else -> UNKNOWN
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However i dont know how to use it.
Can anybody show me the way to work with enums?

Comment: What library are you using for parsing JSON to Kotlin?

Comment: Gson. Does it have to do with that?

Comment: Look at the response you got, depending on the library there are different annotations or steps

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GSON library for serialization/deserialization enum classes are supported by default.

You need to define your `MyResponses` class as below:

```kotlin
 enum class MyResponses {
        @SerializedName("register")
        REGISTER,
        @SerializedName("upload")
        UPLOAD,
        @SerializedName("delete")
        DELETE
    }
```

Take into account the `@SerializedName` annotation in order to deserialize correctly the "ac" property of your json.
Then, use a simple adapter class to deserialize:

```kotlin
class Response(val ac: MyResponses)


fun deserialize(json : String = "{\\\"ac\\\": \\\"upload\\\"}") : Response {
    return Gson().getAdapter(Response::class.java).fromJson(json)
}
```

Comment: I ll try this very soon and i ll post you!